# How to Update List State to show updates in Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to have a list that updates on the fly, it may change a few fields or many.
The initial update at `updateItems()` is fine, everything displays as it should,
however consecutive updates at updateOneItem are ignored by Jetpack Compose.

```kotlin
// ****ViewModel code
val _itemList: MutableStateFlow<List<Item>> = MutableStateFlow(emptyList())

fun updateItems() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _itemList.value = itemRepository.getItems()
    }
}

fun updateOneItem(newVal:Int){
    _itemList.value[_itemList.value.indexOf(item)].weight = newVal
    //this is where I cannot have an update show up in compose no matter what
    _itemList.tryEmit(_itemList.value)
}
// ****continued ViewModel Code
```

I've been trying to copy the list, also tried `mutableStateListOf` but so far nothing works.

Comment: Compose only updates if the value of a state changes. Editing a list item does not result in a value change as the list is still the same object, so you have to create a copy of your list, edit it and emit that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Flow can't know when some mutable property of the containing object changes. When you try to emit it, it checks the address of the object - it's the same as it was - and ignores that emit.

You can force it by creating a copy of the list.

But the cleanest way is using `mutableStateListOf` and making your item an immutable data class, then you can easily update it by creating a copy. Check out [Why is immutability important in functional programming?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-immutability-important-in-functional-programming)

It can look like this:

```kotlin
data class Item(val weight: Int)

private val _itemList = mutableStateListOf<Item>()
val itemList: List<Item> = _itemList

fun updateItems() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _itemList.addAll(itemRepository.getItems())
    }
}

fun updateOneItem(newVal:Int){
    val index = _itemList.indexOf(item)
    _itemList[index] = _itemList[index].copy(weight = newVal)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a very helpful answer, it worked perfectly, one question that I wasn't able to answer is why `List<Item>` works as state, shouldn't it be `State<List<Item>>` ?

Comment: @DavidA no, if you check `mutableStateListOf` implementation, you'll see that it's subclass of `MutableList` and implements `StateObject` interface. It's not `State<List<Item>>`, that's why we don't use delegation with a list, there's no `value`. The fact that interface only shows a `List` doesn't stop Compose from reacting on `StateObject` changes.

Comment: how can call in composeable state?  can we delegate by collectAsStateWithLifecycle?

Comment: @PhilDukhov when I convert the Mutable live data to observeAsState, it works fine. Can we rely on this solution as well?

Comment: @Rameshbabu live data should work fine too, the key here is storing data with immutable objects

Comment: what if the list contains Result<item>?