# Compose slider should respond to manual changes and value changes from external source

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create a slider in Jetpack Compose that can be manipulated manually and stores the value in a DB. At the same time, the slider should react to changes made by a coroutine when the value in the DB is changed.

[image]

I get either one or the other. Here is the version that reacts to the slider change (and updates the DB and external source), but doesn't update the slider when the external source has new values. How can I also set the slider to the new value if the external source writes a new value to the DB?

```
@Composable
fun showAllLights(lightsViewModel: LightsViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {

    val allLights = lightsViewModel.lightsAndGroups.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
    val allLightsByGroupType = allLights.value.filter { it.groupType == "Room" }
    val allGroups = allLightsByGroupType.distinctBy { it.groupId }
    val allLightsGrouped = allLights.value.groupBy {
        it.groupId ?: -1L
    }

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        items(allGroups) { currentGroup ->
            val currentGroupId = currentGroup.groupId ?: -1L

            val lightsByKey = allLightsGrouped.filterKeys { it == currentGroupId }
            LazyRow(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                lightsByKey.forEach { (key, value) ->
                    items(value) { light ->
                        singleLightCard(
                            light
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun singleLightCard(light: ViewLights, lightsViewModel: LightsViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {

    var initialBrightness = ((light.brightness * 100).toFloat() / 254).roundToInt().toFloat()
    var valueSlider by remember { mutableStateOf(initialBrightness) }

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(128.dp)
            .width(144.dp),
    ) {
        Column(
        ) {
            ConstraintLayout(
            ) {
                val (lightBrightnessSlider) = createRefs()

                Slider(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .constrainAs(lightBrightnessSlider) {
                            bottom.linkTo(
                                parent.bottom
                            )
                        }
                        .height(15.dp),
                    value = valueSlider,
                    onValueChange =  {
                        valueSlider = it
                        val errorMessage = lightsViewModel.onLightBrightnessChange(light, it)
                    },
                    valueRange = 1f..100f,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly share the data type of **lightsViewModel.lightsAndGroups** object or share the viewmodel code.

Comment: The data type is Flow<List<ViewLights>>

Comment: Kindly check weather you are creating a different list object every time when data changes in the viewmodel before emitting.

Comment: **allLights** (State) is the same, **allGroups** (List) is a different object when changing a status of a light. No matter if in the app or in the external source.

Comment: Btw. with the same list I am showing the on/off status of the light as the background of the card. This is working. Only the slider will not update the brightness.

Comment: The code you have given looks fine. Whenever **lightsViewModel.lightsAndGroups** changes, recomposition will be triggered. 

Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71596921) for some possible solutions. If you solved the issue kindly post the solution here.

Comment: I am not sure, if that is the problem. I was logging initialBrightness and valueSlider. initialBrightness is getting the correct value in all cases, but valueSlider will only have the remembered value. How can I overwrite the valueSlider value?

Comment: From the viewmode list itself data is coming incorrectly...?

Comment: No, only the remembered slider value is not getting updated. The value in the list is correct, but the slider is not moving to the new position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to replace

```
var valueSlider by remember { mutableStateOf(initialBrightness) }
```

with

```
var valueSlider by remember(initialBrightness) { mutableStateOf(initialBrightness) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are updating the database with the latest brightness value and the database emits whenever there is a change in the data, you don't need to create a `valueSlider` state. You can simply use `initialBrightness` as the value of the slider and each time DB is updated(by manual or external action) the `lightsViewModel.lightsAndGroups` will emit a new data set and the sliders of light brightness will be updated with the latest data.

PS: There can only be one source of truth for the slider. So we move that to the DB. If you really want to use `valueSlider` state, you can convert it to a `val` and then use `derivedStateOf` instead of `mutableStateOf`