# Recomposing 2d array element when its variable changes in Compose with Clean Architecture

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, clean-architecture

I'm trying to achieve a fast image recomposition on a board when at least one variable from the objects in a 2d array changes.

I had a 2d array implemented as `Array<Array<Cell>>`, yet, to achieve recomposition, I created a duplicate `remember` variable on the `Screen`. This worked fast enough, but it resulted in duplication of code from the business logic of the application and did not allow us to use all the functions, so it was not the right way.

Structure of date class `Cell`:

```
data class Cell(
    val x: Int,
    val y: Int,
    var isOpen: Boolean = false,
    var index: Int = 0
)
```

`Screen` code:

```
val row = 5
val col = 5
val board = viewModel.board.value

Column(Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
    Row(Modifier.horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
        Column {
            for (i in 0 until row) {
                Row {
                    for (j in 0 until col) {

                        val currentItem = remember(board) { mutableStateOf(board[i][j]) }  //duplicate remember variable

                        Image(
                            painter = painterResource(
                                id = if (currentItem.value.isOpen) {
                                    when (currentItem.value.index) {
                                        0 -> R.drawable.ic_num_0
                                        1 -> R.drawable.ic_num_1
                                        2 -> R.drawable.ic_num_3
                                        else -> R.drawable.ic_field
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    R.drawable.ic_field
                                }
                            ),
                            contentDescription = null,
                            modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                                currentItem.value = currentItem.value.copy(isOpen = true) // duplication of code
                                board[i][j].isOpen = true                                 // from the business logic of the application
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`ViewModel` code:

```
private val _board = mutableStateOf<Array<Array<Cell>>>(arrayOf())
val board: State<Array<Array<Cell>>> = _board

fun start() {
    _board.value = createBoard()// Use case that returns Array(row) { i -> Array(col) { j -> Cell(i, j) } }
}
```

After that, I added a duplicate 2d array `Array<Array<MutableState<Cell>>>` to the `ViewModel`. Yet, to update it, I had to add two double loops — one to convert `Array<Array<Cell>>` to `Array<Array<MutableState<Cell>>>` and the other to convert `Array<Array<MutableState<Cell>>>` back to `Array<Array<Cell>>`.
This helped to get rid of duplicate code on the `Screen` and allowed us to implement all the functions, but predictably greatly increased the processing time for clicks.

`Screen` code:

```
val row = 5
val col = 5
val board = viewModel.board.value

Column(Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
    Row(Modifier.horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
        Column {
            for (i in 0 until row) {
                Row {
                    for (j in 0 until col) {

                        val currentItem = remember(board) { viewModel.boardState[i][j] }

                        Image(
                            painter = painterResource(
                                id = if (currentItem.value.isOpen) {
                                    when (currentItem.value.index) {
                                        0 -> R.drawable.ic_num_0
                                        1 -> R.drawable.ic_num_1
                                        2 -> R.drawable.ic_num_3
                                        else -> R.drawable.ic_field
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    R.drawable.ic_field
                                }
                            ),
                            contentDescription = null,
                            modifier = Modifier.combinedClickable(
                                onClick = {
                                    viewModel.updateBoard(
                                        board[i][j],
                                        Event.OnClick
                                    )
                                }
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`ViewModel` code:

```
fun updateBoard(cell: Cell? = null, event: Event? = null) {
    val newBoard = boardState.map { row -> row.map { item -> item.value }.toTypedArray() }.toTypedArray() // one double loops
    _board.value = updateBoard(newBoard, cell, event) // Use case that returns Array(row) { i -> Array(col) { j -> Cell(i, j) } }
    boardState = board.value.map { row -> row.map { item -> mutableStateOf(item) }.toTypedArray() }.toTypedArray() // two double loops
}
```

**Question:** How can I achieve fast recomposition when changing the variable of any object in a 2d array?

**Note:** In my project, I follow the principles of Clean Architecture, so I cannot use `Array<Array<MutableState<Cell>>>` at the domain level, because `MutableState` is part of the `androidx` library.

Also, I want to add that when you click on a 2d field cell, **other cells can change**, and not just the one that was clicked.

Perhaps this can be solved using `MutableStateFlow`, however, unlike `MutableState`, it does not cause elements to be recomposed. Maybe there are other ways that I don't know about.

**Update:** I tried to cast `Array<Array<Cell>>` to `Array<Array<MutableStateFlow<Cell>>>`, and convert `StateFlow` to Compose `State` in `Screen` using `collectAsState()`, however this results in an error.

`Screen`:

```
val board by viewModel.board

Column(Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
    Row(Modifier.horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
        Column {
            for (i in 0 until row) {
                Row {
                    for (j in 0 until col) {

                        val currentItem = remember(board) { board[i][j].collectAsState() } // error
                            ...
```

`ViewModel`:

```
private val _board = mutableStateOf<Array<Array<MutableStateFlow<Cell>>>>(arrayOf())
val board: State<Array<Array<MutableStateFlow<Cell>>>> = _board

fun updateBoard(cell: Cell? = null, event:Event? = null) {
    _board.value = updateBoard(board.value, cell, event)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomposition happens when you read state. So I think the most clean way is to use a list of mutable state for each cell, and only read in the cell. Note that if you'll inline `Cell`, it's gonna cause whole collection recomposition as `Row` and `Column` are inline functions which prevents Compose from smart recomposition.

```
@Composable
fun Test() {
    val m = 10
    val n = 10
    val state = remember {
        List(m) {
            List(n) { mutableStateOf(0) }
        }
    }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Column {
        for (i in 0 until m)
            Row {
                for (j in 0 until n)
                    Cell(
                        state = state[i][j],
                        onClick = {
                            state[i][j].value += 1
                        },
                    )
            }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun Cell(
    state: State<Int>,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    Text(
        state.value.toString(),
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable(onClick = onClick)
            .padding(10.dp)
    )
}
```

If for some reason you need to do that on data layer and wanna use immutable states for some architectural reasons, you can use same approach with flows - you just need to have a point where it can be collected for each value separately.

```
@Composable
fun Test() {
    val m = 10
    val n = 10
    val state = remember {
        MutableStateFlow(
            List(m) {
                List(n) { 0 }
            }
        )
    }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Column {
        for (i in 0 until m)
            Row {
                for (j in 0 until n)
                    Cell(
                        valueStateFlow = remember {
                            state.map { it[i][j] }.stateIn(coroutineScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, state.value[i][j])
                        },
                        onClick = {
                            state.value = state.value.toMutableList().also {column->
                                column[i] = column[i].toMutableList().also { row ->
                                    row[j] = row[j] + 1
                                }.toImmutableList()
                            }.toImmutableList()
                        },
                    )
            }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun Cell(
    valueStateFlow: StateFlow<Int>,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    val value by valueStateFlow.collectAsState()
    Text(
        value.toString(),
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable(onClick = onClick)
            .padding(10.dp)
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! `neverEqualPolicy` really makes recompose faster. However, unfortunately, this policy in this case causes the entire field with cells to be recompose. With a small boards it's not that big of a deal, but with larger boards it causes a click delay... I've been trying to figure out how I can set neverEqualPolicy on a per-cell basis, but I haven't had any success. As a big Jetpack Compose expert, can you give me a hint on how I can get only changed cells to be updated?

Comment: And I have one more question, @Phil. If I want to pass a data to handle clicks in my business logic, how can I pass an updated value to this state, if after clicking on one cell, other cells can be updated? Should the data object itself be passed instead of `{ 0 }` in the example?

Comment: @VictorSklyarov I have updated my answer. Your second question is unclear, if it is still relevant after my new answer, clarify it.

Comment: I tried the second example and it has amazing responsiveness! But, as I understand it, it only works with the cell that was clicked. In my second question, I wanted to say that double-clicking may update other cells that were not clicked, and which also need to be recompose.

Comment: [Here is a link to a real project](https://github.com/victorsklyarov/Minesweeper), maybe it will tell you better what effect I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @VictorSklyarov it should work the same for any updated cell

Comment: I tried to apply this update again by trying to change `Int` to `data class Cell()` and I got stuck... Unfortunately the board doesn't update at all now...

Comment: @VictorSklyarov I guess that you have var property in your Cell, and modify it? it's not gonna work. You can made it `val` and update with copy method - check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71596921/3585796) for details.

Comment: Yes, I have tried changing `var` to `val` and moving the cell coordinates to a separate `data class`, but apparently I am doing something wrong... @Phil if you have a free minute, I would be very grateful if you were able to look [my repository](https://github.com/victorsklyarov/Minesweeper/tree/error) and point out the error, although I understand that you are very busy and you don't have time to look at someone else's code

Comment: @VictorSklyarov you don't seems to be using `counter` in your cell code, that's why you don't see the update. with `isOpened = !row[j].isOpened` it works

Comment: Yes, it starts to work, but this action only opens the cell, but does not set the image according to the index. Is there any way to synchronize two two-dimensional arrays, one of which is processed in the business logic, and the second, which is responsible for updating the UI, without resorting to a complete recompose of the `board`? Or maybe it's possible to use the `board` directly, also without resorting to a complete recompose?

Comment: @VictorSklyarov it's much easier to do with a single source of truth. But otherwise, you can have a list of selected coordinates on UI level and other info on data level - e.g.  you can combine two flows to get final data entry. In any case the point is to collect only on cell level and only data that this particular cell needs

Answer (score 0):

Expose your ViewModel's board as a StateFlow:

```
private var _board = MutableStateFlow<Array<Array<Cell>>>() // Empty init
val board: StateFlow<Array<Array<Cell>>> = _board
```

Then in your screen you can collect is as:

```
val state = viewModel.board.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
```

You should then delete the variable remembering duplication you are doing in the screen and notify your ViewModel on click, so the exposed StateFlow is updated. This way, there will be recomposition every time you click on a cell.

```
val currentItem = board[i][j])
```

For better composition performance you should also consider:

- Using `LazyColumn` and `LazyRow` to display the cells
- Using Kotlin Immutable collections instead of nested arrays. Check this article for better understanding how this can help your Compose performance: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/jetpack-compose-stability-explained-79c10db270c8

Comment: This answer results in an error that `MutableStateFlow` has `Not enough information to infer type variable T`. When setting `MutableStateFlow<Array<Array<Cell>>>(arrayOf())` and using this answer, **there is no recompose at all**. `LazyColumn` and `LazyRow` are not used, because there will be scrolling of individual rows, but it is necessary to scroll through **the entire field**.

Comment: I updated the answer. You are blocking recomposition with the duplication you are making in the screen. You should avoid this by removing that duplication and update the value of your cells in your ViewModel. If with these changes you have performance issues, you should debug the stability of your composables and try to fix it (the medium post in my answer), because you are using an unstable collection (array) that will lead to the recomposition of every cell every time something changes.

Comment: The `_board` variable still has a `No value passed for parameter 'value'` error because no initialization value was passed to the constructor. But even when initializing its `arrayOf()` with the updated response, just like before the update, the recompose doesn't happen... It happens only after the configuration changes when the screen is rotated.

Comment: Can you share how are you emitting the new board values of the StateFlow? When you load the whole board at start or when you update the value after a click

Comment: I will be able to share how I process board in a while.  However, I can immediately say that when creating for initialization and reinitialization, I use an empty use case without parameters, assigning the returned result of use case to `_board`.  On subsequent interaction with the already initialized board, I pass the address of `Cell[i][j]` and the event that happened (`onClick`, `onDoubleClick`, `onLongClick`), and re-assign the already updated two-dimensional array `_board`

Comment: More precisely, not an empty use case constructor, but only `_board` is passed, initialized with initial value `_board = arrayOf()`

Comment: It is ok to start with an empty array and emit a new one later, but I think you are not recomposing because you are not emitting the value with the StateFlow. You should use _board.emit(yourBoardArray) or _board.tryEmit(yourBoardArray) if you want your screen to collect it properly

Comment: Tried to use `.emit()`, but it still doesn't trigger recompose... Also updated only after screen rotation